# Difference between two SELECTs

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE navigation_trees (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    parent_id INT NULL,
    template_id NOT NULL
)
```

Because there is a foreign key whereby the parent_id references the id of the same table, attempting to delete a row which is referenced by the parent_id of another row violates referential integrity. SQL Server will not allow ON DELETE CASCADE because of the (obvious) potential for circular reference cascades.

So, I'm trying to delete all rows that have a template ID other than ( 158, 159 ). In order to do that, I'm trying to select all rows which are NOT the target of a reference (i.e. no other row's parent_id is this row's id), delete them, and then repeat the process in a loop until there are no more to delete. Each time a batch is deleted, any which had a parent_id will free up the reference rows on the next pass.

Initially I was doing this with temporary tables, but it seemed to still run afoul of the constraint. Here is a query using two methods (with temp table, and direct on the table itself) to try to identify the rows to delete:

```
-- method one: temp table for filtering template IDs
SELECT id, parent_id
INTO #navTrees
FROM navigation_trees
WHERE template_id NOT IN ( 158, 159 )

SELECT DISTINCT tnt1.id
INTO #set1
FROM #navTrees AS tnt1
LEFT OUTER JOIN #navTrees AS tnt2 ON tnt1.id = tnt2.parent_id
WHERE tnt2.parent_id IS NULL

-- method two: filtering template IDs directly in the join
SELECT DISTINCT tnt1.id
INTO #set2
FROM navigation_trees AS tnt1
LEFT OUTER JOIN navigation_trees AS tnt2 ON tnt1.id = tnt2.parent_id
WHERE tnt2.parent_id IS NULL
    AND tnt1.template_id NOT IN ( 158, 159 )

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM #set1
-- Produces: 106023

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM #set2
-- Produces: 102575

DROP TABLE #navTrees
DROP TABLE #set1
DROP TABLE #set2
```

The temp table method seems to be catching extra incorrect rows, and that's why it fails referential integrity checking. Why do they produce different numbers of rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After separating the non-`(158, 159)` templates into a temporary table using the first method, you are not looking at the `(158, 159)` templates any more. But, as the figures suggest, some of the non-`(158, 159)` templates must be parents to some of the `(158, 159)` ones **only**. The first method doesn't filter them out, while the second one does.

You could still use the first method, but you need to use the original set as the right side of the left join. Or just go with your second, single-query method.

Comment: Or put another way, the second set properly considers children that are of any `template_id`, not just children in the filtered set. The data obviously has some parents that cannot be deleted even though their `template_ids` are not 158 or 159.

Comment: That makes more sense to me, and matces up with the second method set being smaller. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that in method two the tnt2 data set still has templates 158 and 159 in it. therefore some records that belong to these templates can be joining to tnt1 giving you more records than method 1. This cant happen in method one because these templates were removed from both sets of data (tnt1 and tnt2) before the join. Try adding this to the WHERE clause of Method 2 `AND tnt2.template_id NOT IN ( 158, 159 )`

Comment: That was my initial thought, but method two *doesn't produce more results*, it produces fewer! When I add the additional condition to the WHERE clause in method 2, I end up with *0* results returned; I'm not sure why that is either :(